# windows ping cmd help

Tags: windows, command-line, ping

I'm looking at the ping command help and i cant see a parameter to change the time between pings. I don't mean the timeout time.

(For example i want to send a ping every 5 seconds)

Is this possible?

Comment: By default the time delay between two pings is equal to 1 second. If your need is to reduce the delay between two pings
You can try this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1586246/how-can-i-do-a-ping-every-500-ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from a broadband [forum](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php?t=122641):

Batch file

```
@echo off
:start
ping -n 1 <destination>
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
GOTO start
```

or in a single command

```
for /L %i in (1,0,2) do @ping -n 1 <destination> & ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
```

Comment: ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
Whats this doing?

Comment: `> NUL` redirects a program's output to the special file `NUL`, like `/dev/null` on Unix. And `2>&1` redirects stderr (all error messages) to the same place.

Comment: In general, this is a way to make it wait: "5 pings" to your own computer, without displaying results, before coming back to the beginning and doing the ping your are interested in.

Comment: aaah. Seems a bit hacky thought :(

Comment: tm1rbrt: If you're on Vista you can also use `timeout` if that feels less hacky :-)

Comment: Without thinking, I named the batch file 'ping.bat' and marvelled at the many windows created as it called itself. Does the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

`ping -t` will send forever, but at the default rate.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 3rd party FPing tool to do what you want:

fping hostIP -c -t 5000

http://www.kwakkelflap.com/fping.html