# How can I do a ping every 500 ms?

Tags: cmd.exe, ping

By default the time delay between two pings is equal to 1 second. My need is to reduce the delay between two pings to 500 ms (0.5 seconds). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? There is no benefit of doing this, which is why ping itself can't do this.

Comment: @LPChip That's an interesting theory, but sending more than 1 ping per second is actually something very common. When you want to measure packet loss with reasonable precision and don't want to spend hours doing it, reducing the interval to a fraction of a second is the way to go.

Comment: @jcaron no its not... If you want to measure packet loss, you increase the size of a packet, which ping does support.

Comment: @LPChip To get a reasonable measure of packet loss, you need to send many packets. Like 100. If you are stuck with a 1 second interval, it takes 100 seconds. If you can send them a 0.1 or 0.01 intervals, it takes 10 seconds or 1 second. Also, increasing packet size does not help you measuring packet loss for a given size (packet loss may vary with the size of the packets).

Comment: @LPChip also, as can be seen in the answers below, this is something that is useful enough that there are multiple tools that can do it (and of course the Unix versions of ping also do).

Comment: @jcaron just because people don't understand how to properly measure packetloss, and just want to increase the frequency of the ping, which causes more overhead on the network, than to increase the packet size which more effectively to measure packet loss doesn't mean that is the way to do it.

Comment: @jcaron its the same as knocking on the door. You knock on the door, but the other person does not hear you. Instead of knocking quicker to hope that they now hear you, it will really help if you knock harder.

Comment: @LPChip Longer and shorter packets have somewhat different failure modes so it sometimes makes sense to use different length. Then again, using longer ot shorter pauses is pretty much legitimate and that's why ping has corresponding options. On Windows, the pause is hardcoded to 1s, but on Linux the pause is limited only by the network stack performance.

Comment: @LPChip Interesting analogy, but actually wrong. Increasing packet size increases your chances of dropping packets if the reason for the packet loss is errors on the link. Increasing frequency does not. Changing one or the other means you don't measure the same thing. At all.

Comment: On Unix, "flood ping" is so normal that the `ping` command has a separate mode for it, where it prints a dot for every packet sent and a backspace for every (non-duplicate) packet received.

Comment: If you need 500ms between pings even if the pings take longer than 500ms to return then the question needs to reflect that. The current answers wait for a response (or a timeout from no response), then wait 500ms, then do the next ping.

Comment: @LPChip In industrial systems, it's not uncommon to have packets from a device every couple of ms, at least 10 packets a second and often a heck of a lot more. Increasing ping speed to twice a second is only a start.

Comment: You now have a lot of different ways to achieve what you want. Did you use any of them? If so can you give that answer a Checkmark Icon, so we know this question is solved?

Comment: Start two regular ping processes with a 500 ms offset? They might loose their offset over time though

Comment: @LPChip increasing packet size only helps detect packet loss if the problem is in the signal quality. if you're looking for intermittent failure, like the connection dropping out for <1sec once every 15 minutes, then rapid pings would help you not to just skip over it when it happens.

Comment: @LPChip What if there is a fire-wall configured as drop packets by pps?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can take the [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-6.0) class and wrap it in a PowerShell function. I kept it very easy, you can tinker with it to get the output you want.

Here's the function:

- Computername accepts internal + external IP Adresses, ComputerNames, URLs etc.
- Count = How many ping packets to send
- Timeout specifies the maximum number of milliseconds (after sending the echo message) to wait for the ICMP echo reply message.
- Interval = How many milliseconds to wait before next ping.

.

```
Function New-IntervalPing {

    [Alias("iping")]
    Param(
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [int]$Count = 4,
        [int]$TimeOut = 100,
        [int]$Interval = 500
    )

    1..$Count | ForEach-Object {
        $Ping = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping]::New()
        $Ping.Send($ComputerName,$TimeOut)
        start-sleep -Milliseconds $Interval
    }
}
```

usage:

```
PS C:\Users\SimonS> iping google.com -count 2 -interval 300


Status        : Success
Address       : 172.217.168.14
RoundtripTime : 6
Options       : System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions
Buffer        : {97, 98, 99, 100...}

Status        : Success
Address       : 172.217.168.14
RoundtripTime : 4
Options       : System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions
Buffer        : {97, 98, 99, 100...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Is it possible to use ip address instead of CompturName ?

Comment: @geek225 yes, you can also specify an IP Adress instead: `New-Ping 10.0.0.226 500`. `Test-Connection` doesn't care if it's IP or Name

Comment: I like this one because it doesn't required installing a separate app. I always think the best Answer should at least provide a way to do that, even if using a separate program is easier.

Answer (score 23):

On Linux it is possible (recently minimum time was changed to 200ms = 0.2):

```
ping -i 0.2 server.com
```

Root can issue shorter time:

```
ping -i 0.01 server.com
```

Comment: one would need to use 0.5 to achieve 500ms

Comment: And the tags mention windows (cmd.exe)

Comment: This also works on macOS.

Answer (score 18):

You can do this with [nping](https://nmap.org/nping/) (from the makers of [nmap](https://nmap.org/))

1. First [download](https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.80-setup.exe) and install the **nmap** package which includes **nping**.
2. In a command prompt change the directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap`
3. Now run the following command: `nping --delay 500ms --count 0 <target ip address>`
   (the `--count 0` option sets it to a continuous ping)

....from [Nping Reference Guide](https://nmap.org/book/nping-man-briefoptions.html):

```
Usage: nping [Probe mode] [Options] {target specification}
....
....
TIMING AND PERFORMANCE:
  Options which take <time> are in seconds, or append 'ms' (milliseconds),
  's' (seconds), 'm' (minutes), or 'h' (hours) to the value (e.g. 30m, 0.25h).
  --delay <time>                   : Adjust delay between probes.
  --rate  <rate>                   : Send num packets per second.
```

Comment: holly smokes that is amazing and terrifying. the power is right there.

Answer (score 10):

- In PowerShell

```bat
$cnt=0; while ($cnt -le 9) {$cnt++; Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 500; Test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -Count 1}
```

- One option using aliases:

```bat
$cnt=0;while($cnt -le 9){$cnt++;Test-Connection 1.1.1.1  -Cou 1; sleep -M 500}
```

Super golfed version from **[@wasif-hasan](https://superuser.com/users/1113181/wasif-hasan)** comment suggestion:

```bat
0..9|%{test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -cou 1;sleep -m 500}
```

- Outputs/Results:

```bat
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       18       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       20       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       15       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       17       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       15       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       19       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       16       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       16       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       18       
LAME_SLUG     1.1.1.1         1.1.1.1          2606:4700:4700::1111                     32       19
```

---

- Some further reading for PowerShell:

  [√]  **[While | $cnt+](https://ss64.com/ps/while.html)**

  [√]  **[Test-Connection](https://ss64.com/ps/test-connection.html)**

  [√]  **[Start-Sleep | Sleep](https://ss64.com/ps/start-sleep.html)**

  [√]  **[Remove-Variable | Rv](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-variable.html)**

---

---

- In Bat/CMD:

```bat
@echo off 

:loop
pathping 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 500 >nul 2>nul 
ping 151.101.193.69 -n 1 -4 & goto=:loop
```

- Or with a predefined ping/loop limit:

```
@echo off & setlocal
```

:loop
pathping 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 500 >nul 2>nul
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -4 & set /a "_cnt+=1+0"
if **%_cnt% leq 10 (goto:loop)**else goto:eof

---

Use `pathping` from Microsoft and comes with Windows

```bat
C:\Users\ecker>where pathping
C:\Windows\System32\PATHPING.EXE
```

---

```bat
C:\Users\ecker>PATHPING.EXE /?
Usage: pathping [-g host-list] [-h maximum_hops] [-i address] [-n]
                [-p period] [-q num_queries] [-w timeout]
                [-4] [-6] target_name

Options:
    -g host-list     Loose source route along host-list.
    -h maximum_hops  Maximum number of hops to search for target.
    -i address       Use the specified source address.
    -n               Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
    -p period        Wait period milliseconds between pings.
    -q num_queries   Number of queries per hop.
    -w timeout       Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
    -4               Force using IPv4.
    -6               Force using IPv6.
```

---

**Obs.:** When **-p** is specified, pings are sent individually to each intermediate hop. When **-w** is specified, multiple pings can be sent in parallel. It is therefore possible to choose a Timeout parameter that is less than the wait Period * Number of hops.

---

- Some further reading for cmd/bat:

  [√] **[PathPing](https://ss64.com/nt/pathping.html)**

Comment: A super golfed version would be: `0..9|%{test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -cou 1;sleep -m 500}`

Comment: @WasifHasan 
I already added in the post, very good, thanks ...

Answer (score 9):

You can't change the time between each ping request in the Windows command line. You'll need a 3rd party tool like fping or TruePing

Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/200468/how-can-i-set-a-short-timeout-with-the-ping-command

Comment: I looked into this. fPing is only a linux program, and TruePing gets deleted by my antivirus for being a trojan.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this is simply to run two pings each in their own window. (Not strictly 1 every 500ms, but it would be 2 per second.)

This gets cumbersome fast, but something like 5 at once is possible.